# ElasticHQ vs Marvel

Tags: elasticsearch

I looking for,  a document, an article or an benchmark about the difference between  ElasticHQ and Marvel.

I would like to know which is the best ?
What are your experience feedback in relation to one of the two tools ?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the founder of ElasticHQ. What Garry says is correct, but I can only be fair and speak for ElasticHQ as some of the differences that may or may not matter to you...

- ElasticHQ has a bit more features in the realm of Management (not the monitoring parts), ie. creating indices, mappings, flushing, optimizing, etc...
- ElasticHQ also has a neat Diagnostics utility that uses rules to alert you to anything out of the norm.
- ElasticHQ is Apache-Licensed and Open Source. Free to use, fork, contribute. No vendor lock-in.
- ElasticHQ does NOT require you to deploy anything on the ElasticSearch cluster. It runs completely in the browser.

Fair to mention there are other monitoring/management systems out there, such as BigDesk, or Sematext that should also be included in any bake-off.

My $.02.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any such articles, however, I have used both ElasticHQ and Marvel on Elasticsearch clusters. In my experience I would now always go with Marvel.

The major drawback for you though might be that Marvel isn't free. It's free for development environments only. As far as I'm concerned this is the only real "draw-back". However, for enterprise users such as myself this is actually a benefit that gives some guarantee of support and continued development.

Other than this, why would I go with Marvel over ElasticHQ? One reason really, Marvel is aesthetically very beautifully designed and well laid out. Both Marvel and ElasticHQ have like for like features as these are actually limited by the Elasticsearch API end-points.

If the license fee is an issue, go with ElasticHQ, if not then go with Marvel.